# Postgres sql file insert hanging

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to insert data from an sql file which is about 1.6GB in size. I used the command:

```
\i filename.sql
```

however it had been running for well over ten minutes. Initially when I ran it I got output such as below:

```
psql:xxx.sql:1102: ERROR:  role "xxx" does not exist
psql:xxx.sql:1124: ERROR:  relation "xxx" already exists
psql:xxx.sql:1127: ERROR:  role "xxx" does not exist
psql:xxx.sql:1138: ERROR:  relation "xxx" already exists
psql:xxx.sql:1141: ERROR:  role "xxx" does not exist
psql:xxx.sql:1177: ERROR:  relation "xxx" already exists
psql:xxx.sql:1180: ERROR:  role "xxx" does not exist
psql:xxx.sql:1191: ERROR:  relation "xxx" already exists
psql:xxx.sql:1194: ERROR:  role "xxx" does not exist
psql:xxx.sql:1223: ERROR:  relation "xxx" already exists
psql:xxx.sql:1226: ERROR:  role "xxx" does not exist
psql:xxx.sql:1237: ERROR:  relation "xxx" already exists
psql:xxx.sql:1240: ERROR:  role "xxx" does not exist
```

This continues until the final output was:

```
psql:xxx.sql:1183266: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "xxx"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY mo_logs, line 1: "2  +6421558671     +15759151518    LolWithPlus     unable to deliver, dropping : undefined method `bytesize' for..."
```

Then the console shows nothing new since then. On my first attempt I thought it was hanging so exited but got the following output:

```
Cancel request sent
```

This leads me to believe the script is still running but I have no way of telling. Can anyone advise how I can either diagnose what is going on or give me an indication of whether the insert is failing as shown by it hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the SQL script contains several `COPY` statements.
One of them (`COPY TO mo_logs`) failed, and another of them (`COPY TO midn_protections`) was running when you interrupted processing.

Normally `psql` continues working after an error and will just execute the next statement. To avoid that, start it with the option `--set ON_ERROR_STOP=on`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Was thinking it was still running but it would be nice to see some logging other than errors to show that progress is being made. Is this possible? Tried finding a command but no luck other than basic logging being sent to a file of my choosing.

Comment: You can use the `-a` option of `psql` to have it echo the current statement.

Comment: So would that be `\i filename.sql -a`

Comment: No, `psql -a`. Inside psql you'd have to `\set ECHO all`.